# Androidアプリから画像をSNSシェアをする機能を実装する時に、エラーが出ないので修正点がわからない

Tags: java, android, twitter, kotlin

#### 実現したいこと

Androidアプリから、画面のスクリーンショットを保存して、アプリから直接Twitterに画像をシェアする機能を実現したいです。

現状は、開発しているAndroidアプリからTwitterに移動はできるのですが、画像が自動的にTwitterに移動できていないので、プログラムをどのように修正すればいいかアドバイスをいただきたいです。

#### 試したこと

`ShareCompat`に関して調べて、teratailで未回答の「[Androidアプリで画像をTwitterにシェアしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/210893)」という質問を見つけ、記載されていたコードを動かしてみました。

別の記事で、[iOSとAndroidのTweet機能を組み込む方法について書かれた記事](http://www.bitz.co.jp/weblog/?date=201908)を見つけて、双方を組み合わせようとしています。

#### 現状の問題点

アプリがインストールされていなくても、Webブラウザ経由でTwitterにログインもしくは新規登録できるようになりましたが、文字や画像などアプリから共有したいコンテンツをTwitterに移行できていない状態です。

#### 現在のコード

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.snsshare

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.SeekBar
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.core.app.ShareCompat
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //intent button
        val intentTweetButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.intentTweetButton)
        intentTweetButton.setOnClickListener {
            shareTwitter()
        }

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                //ツマミがドラッグされると呼ばれる
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                    // 68 % のようにフォーマト、
                    // この場合、Locale.USが汎用的に推奨される

                    background_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(progress,200,255 - progress))
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                    // ツマミがタッチされた時に呼ばれる
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                    // ツマミがリリースされた時に呼ばれる
                }

            })

        share_button.setOnClickListener() {
            showShareChooser()
        }
    }

    // share intentの実装
    fun shareTwitter() {
        val message = "shareTwitter intent tweet"
        try {
            val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sharingIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            startActivity(sharingIntent)
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("In Exception", "Comes here")
            val i = Intent()
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            i.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            i.data = Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet")
            startActivity(i)
        }

    }

    //share compatの実装
    private fun showShareChooser() {

        val chooserTitle = "共有方法"
        val subject = "メールの件名"
        val text = "アプリタイトル"

        val builder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        builder.setChooserTitle(chooserTitle) // シェアする時のタイトル
            .setSubject(subject) // 件名。使われ方はシェアされた側のアプリによる
            .setText(text) // 本文。使われ方はシェアされた側のアプリによる
            .setType("text/plain") // ストリームで指定したファイルのMIMEタイプ

        // 結果を受け取らなくても良い場合は、ビルダーからそのまま開始できる
        builder.startChooser()
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:max="255"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ShareCompat"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/intentTweetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="intent tweet" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### 追記

[iOSとAndroidのTweet機能を組み込む方法について書かれた記事](http://www.bitz.co.jp/weblog/?date=201908)では、share intent（アプリがスマホに入っていなくてもWebブラウザに移行してツイート編集画面を立ち上げる）を実行した場合、

```
val message = "shareTwitter intent tweet"
```

がツイート編集画面で記入された上で、ツイッターが立ち上がっていましたが、現行のコードを実行してもエミュレーターでは何も記入されていないままでツイート投稿のための編集画面が立ち上がります。

#### 開発環境

Android Studio 3.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahooの知恵袋のほうで回答した者です。

teratailの質問者またはiOSとAndroidのTweet機能を組み込む方法のGitHubところのソースコードをみました。NPPさんのプログラムを走らせてみました。
感想はTwitterと連携が取れていない印象がある。問題を感じたところはshareTwitter()メソッドのtryの部分とshowShareChooser()メソッドです。
連携が取れていないために移行できていないではないでしょうか。
shareTwitter()メソッドのtryの部分で気になることがあります。

ネットで拾った情報が正しければ
旧)com.twitter.android.PostActivityから
新)com.twitter.applib.PostActivityに変更なっています。
https://www.manongdao.com/q-657607.html
https://www.ojit.com/article/654030
ただ、新しいほうで実行するとアプリが落ちます。

お気づきになっているかどうかわかりませんが
iOSとAndroidのTweet機能を組み込む方法のサイトを見ると
下から２番目のiOSの画像にはDialogの表示画像がある。

【Android】ShareCompatを使って簡単にシェアボタンを実装しよう
https://qiita.com/ryokosuge/items/1d016043bf9f20828491

ここのサイトのソースコードの中身にも
// アプリ一覧が表示されるDialogのタイトルの設定
という言葉があります。

つまり、showShareChooser()メソッドはDialogやオプションメニュー
などの形で表示する目的のメソッドと思います。

以下は具体例
Android Tips #35 ShareCompat で簡単に共有アクションをつくる
https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-tips-35-sharecompat/

Answer (score 0):

どうもこんにちは。こちらが参考になるのではないでしょうか。

[SDKを使わないでSNSに投稿する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/le_skamba/items/c9810a0e6df27097d502)

```
val builder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
    builder.setChooserTitle("title");
    builder.setText("message")
    builder.setType("image/jpg")
    builder.addStream(Uri.fromFile(File("画像のパス")))
    builder.startChooser()
```

Comment: @Toku-san ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
ShareCompatしか画像は共有できないということでしょうか。

質問内容に明記し忘れたため、修正しましたが、Share Intentでアプリがスマホにインストールされていない場合は、Webブラウザに移動する場合は現状でも`val message = "shareTwitter intent tweet"`の部分がTwitterに移行できていないです。